# Dice Coefficient vs *Negative* Dice Coefficient..?

Tags: categorical-encoding, image-segmentation

While reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.09570.pdf) I've noticed that they use what they call *negative dice coefficient*. I know that in general the [dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) is a metric commonly used in image segmentation tasks when we want to consider such an overlap measure. Consequently, a penalty to be added to the overall loss function can be defined by setting $1-\text{dice}$ as $\text{dice} \in [0,1]$.

I simply don't understand why these people use a *negative sign* in front of the dice coefficient.

Comment: If the dice coefficient is between 0 (bad) and 1 (good) then you cannot use it directly as a loss function to be minimised, but can if you take a decreasing function of it.

Comment: What if we consider just $1-\text{dice}$ as a penalty term for the loss function? Why this shouldn't work?

Comment: They use "loss = - dice_score", so as "dice_score" goes higher the loss becomes smaller and smaller